# Function Returns "No Solution" Instead Of "Nothing"

Tags: functional-programming, logic-programming, option-type, curry

I have a standard datatype representing formulae of predicate logic. A function representing a natural deduction elimination rule for disjunction might look like:

```
d_el p q =
  if p =: (Dis r s) && q =: (Neg r) then Just s else
  if q =: (Dis r s) && p =: (Neg r) then Just s else
     Nothing where r,s free

x =: y = (x =:= y) == success
```

Instead of evaluating to Nothing when unification fails, the function returns no solutions in `PACKS`:

```
logic> d_el (Dis Bot Top) (Not Bot)
Result: Just Top
More Solutions? [Y(es)/n(o)/a(ll)] n
logic> d_el (Dis Bot Top) (Not Top)
No more solutions.
```

What am I missing, and why doesn't `el` evaluate to `Nothing` when unification fails?

Comment: The language I'm using is Curry, a functional-logic programming langauge (see tags).

Comment: oh - I'm sorry .... ignorance can be quite embarassing ....

Comment: As you probably know, "curry" is also a term that has meaning in other languages (like Haskell, obviously) so maybe you should [add some content to the Stack Overflow wiki page for the `curry` tag](http://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/45806).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is not the best way to use equational constraints. When `a =:= b` fails then complete function clause fails also.
E.g.:

```
xx x = if (x =:= 5) == success then 1 else x
xx x = 3
```

Evaluating `xx 7` results in `3` (not `7`) because `7 =:= 5` completely terminates first clause of the `xx` function.

I think the code should look like this:

```
d_el p q = case (p,q) of
   (Dis a s, Neg b) -> if a == b then Just s else Nothing
   (Neg a, Dis b s) -> if a == b then Just s else Nothing
   _ -> Nothing
```